# getbootstrap 3.0 datetimepicker calendar and time issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to datetimepicker component. I am using datetimepicker with getbootstrap3 css and js files. I am able to see the datetimepicker on the page, but when I click to select date then select time, I can not click back on date again. please see the screen shot [image]

My code is as shown below :

```
<div class='input-group date   col-sm-7'     id='startDate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start_Date" name="start_Date" />
    <label for="end_Date" class="input-group-addon btn">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

The javascript is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#startDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' });
}
```

Datetimepicker is also not working in smart devices. The issue can be seen on windows and smart devices. I see the above issue on all smart devices as well. On smart devices, once I select the date and time, the datetimepicker never closed, I need to click on some other component on the page to close the datetimepicker.

I would appreciate some one could provide a complete working sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: Not all widgets and libraries work on mobile devices.  Many have a special mobile version/library, and the regular (desktop) version won't work on mobile devices.

Comment: Not knowing the tech requirements, have you considering using the html5 date type for the input and then disabling the datetimepicker using modernizr allowing the mobile browser to handle the input?